# Recursion in R, Function not working and no idea why

Tags: r, recursion

Essentially, I want to design a function that takes lists of lists of lists of... where eventually the farthest nested lists will have a vector as a single element, and each list it is nested in will have a vector as its last element.

What I want the function to do is to look at each of the bottom most level nested elements and count how many there are.

For example: Say A is a list of 16 vectors, B is a list of 10 vectors, C is a list of 12 vectors, and D is a list of 8 vectors. X is the list that contains A, B and a vector, and Y is the list that contains C, D and a vector. Z is the list of X,Y and a vector.

The function would take Z, and give an output of 46 (16 + 10 + 12 + 8).

Here's the code i'm using right now:

```
listreader <- function(listoflists)
{
  nlist = listoflists
  ini = 0
  its = 0
  if(length(nlist) > 1)
  {
    for (i in 1:(length(nlist)))
    {
      listreader(nlist[[i]])
    } 
  }
  else
  {
    ini = ini+1
  }
  return(ini)
}
```

Comment: ITYM recursion, not regression.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more why you want to do this? I have a feeling that a list of lists of lists etc with only one element at the end of each tree branch is not the best solution, but I might be wrong. In addition, making your example reproducible would also help greatly.

Comment: Can you please add a reproducible example, especially to clarify what do you mean by "list of vectors" or at least add `str(your_list` to get the structure of your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, only lists that contain no lists should contribute their length to the total. This seems to work:

```
v <- 1:10                               # a vector
A <- replicate(16, v, simplify = FALSE) # a list of vectors
B <- replicate(10, v, simplify = FALSE) # a list of vectors
C <- replicate(12, v, simplify = FALSE) # a list of vectors
D <- replicate( 8, v, simplify = FALSE) # a list of vectors
X <- list(A, B, v)                      # a mixed list
Y <- list(C, D, v)                      # a mixed list
Z <- list(X, Y, v)                      # a mixed list

listreader <- function(x) {
  if (is.list(x)) {
    if (!any(sapply(x, is.list))) {
      return(length(x)) # list of vectors
    } else {
      return(sum(sapply(x, listreader))) # recursion
    }
  } else {
    return(0L) # not a list
  }
}

listreader(Z)
# [1] 46
```

Comment: I think my problem was that I wasn't adding the recursive values, I was just having it return, but this works just as well. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(rapply(Z, function(x){1}))
```

Comment: +1 -- Smart but no: there are list items (loose vectors) in the OP's data that should not be counted. See his example which I reproduced. You get 49, I get 46.